# Change width and height of image in html text in swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have html text returned from the server and I am using a UITextView on the IOS client to render the text. I am first converting the html string to attributed string and then enumerating over the attributes and changing the font, foreground color of the text as needed. Finally I am setting the attributed text of UiTextView. However, when the html contains images and I see that they get cut off when rendered in UITextView.

Any pointers on how I could change the width and height of images contained in the html text in order to fit my phone screen width?

Comment: Try setting `bounds.size.width`, `bounds.size.height` values for `NSTextAttachment.bounds` - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextattachment/1508394-bounds

Answer (score 0):

I use [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) to extract data from html or edit the HTML string. I also have found that when images are present it's easier to manage the layout and format inside a `WKWebView`.

This example also helps to add support for dark mode in your WKWebView.

```
var newsRssBody: String = ""
let css = "@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {body { background-color: rgb(38,38,41); color: white; } a:link { color: #0096e2; } a:visited { color: #9d57df; } }"
try doc.head()?.append("<style>\(css)</style>")
self.newsRssBody = "\(doc)"
```

The headerString line helps with content sizing based on the device.

```
let headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'></header>"
self.webView.loadHTMLString(headerSting + self.newsRssBody, baseURL: nil)
```